# Docker container address used in the AppSettings of another application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

The Web.config file of a legacy web application (A) contains an `appSettings` entry for another legacy web application (B) as follows:

```
<add key="AnotherApplicationUrl" value="http://111.222.33.44/entrypoint" />
```

- Application B has been containerized with Docker, and is running under a random IP.
- Application A has also been containerized with Docker
- Both containers are running on the same machine as separate containers

Can you specify a particular host name to use in the docker-compose.yml?

Is this typically bad practice when working with containers? We need to guarantee that the `appSettings` entry in Application A is the correct address for Application B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a docker-compose file using [`container_name`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name) which specifies the 2 applications as 2 docker services

```
version: "2"
services:
  appB:
    container_name: mycoolappB

  appA:
    container_name: mycoolappA
```

and in appA's web.config, you can set the host as `http://mycoolappB/entrypoint`